# I lost my bitcoin wallet

Tags: wallet

I have an address in an investment site I did some investments. Want to withdraw right now, but I can not remember what wallet that address is linked to. Can I trace an address to a wallet?

Answer (score 2):

With only the bitcoin address, there is no way to discern which wallet was used.

Bitcoin addresses do not contain this sort of information, if they did it would be detrimental to user privacy and security.

Comment: Thanks very much. It there fore mean I will have to forget about that address and wallet.

Comment: That may be the case if you have no other way to trace it. Hopefully you can change your withdrawal address without much trouble. If this answer helped, please remember to mark it as accepted :)